# querystring crossover across sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Here's the situation:

User1 logs in with IE to the web site. Once they pass authentication they go to the default page (page1). On page one, user makes a selection which results in a querystring with parameters, and goes to page 2 as specified in the querystring.

User2 logs in with Chrome (I want to be sure they have a different session). Once they pass authentication they go to page 2 and the querystring is the same as the first user's querystring. Same parameters, and they've bypassed page1!

Looks to me like the querystring is being stored at the application level.. but I thought user sessions should always be truly isolated from each other. I have the same problem with session variables- crossover between users.

Is there a way to guarantee unique sessions as users log in? Any other suggestions? Using C#.net

Comment: .Net? php? What are you using. Can you show some code that you are using and witch is related to the problem?

Comment: This can't be a session issue - can you post some of the code from Page1?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I overcame this by pulling an all nighter and experimenting with IIS7 configuration. I defined a simple test which showed the error (login with IE, click a button, leave session up, launch safari, login). Then I went through every permutation of session state config and retested.

In the end, Session State Mode settings are now: In process, use cookies, name: ASP.NET_SessionID, timeout = 20, regenerate expired session ID = false, Use hosign identity for impersonation = true.

What can I say, it's working!

da